# Simple PHP Forms to Email - Not relaying input information

Tags: php, email, post, input

I'm trying to send the information my form input boxes collect to an email. The email is sending but the email message isn't displaying the information entered in the input boxes.

(This is what I'm getting)

Name:

Number:

Location:

Email:

I'm new to PHP and any advice would be greatly appreciated!

PHP

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone= $_POST['phone'];
$location= $_POST['location'];

$formcontent = "
Name: $name \n
Number: $phone \n
Location: $location \n
Email: $email";

$recipient = "chris@knorthstudios.com";
$subject = "Boston Calling Street Team Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank you";

?>
```

Form code:

```
 <form method="POST" action="contact.php">
     label>Name:</label>
     <input type="text" class="inputbox" name="name" required>

     <label>Age:</label>
     <input class="inputbox" name="age" required>

     <label>Location (City/State): </label>
     <input class="inputbox" name="location" required>

     <label>Phone number:  </label>
     <input class="inputbox" name="phone" required>                        

     <label>E-mail address:</label>
     <input class="inputbox" name="email" required>

     <label>What is your favorite flavor of icecream</label>
     <textarea class="inputbox textinputbox"  name="icecream" required></textarea>

     <input class="streetteamsubmit" type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT FORM">

 </form>
```

Comment: Done any basic debugging, like `var_dump($_POST, $formcontent)` to see what you received and what you built?

Answer (score 0):

a) Turn on error reporting. Add this at the top of your code:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

b) Is the php code and the form on the same file?

Then you should check if the page has been sent by the POST method. The first time that a visitor arrives at the contactform will always be in the GET method. (he just arrives on the page and still have to fill the formfields)

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    // visitor has sent the form
}
```

c) You never know if $_POST elements really exist thus you should check that with the isset() function

```
// initializing with a default value
$name = '';

// overwrite value if $_POST element exists
if(isset($_POST['name']))
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
}
```

d) Under here you will see a very basic example of a good working form with validation.

```
<?php

// Function that validates your formfields and generate errors
function validate($naam, $email)
{
    $errors = array();

    // validation for name
    if(strlen($naam) < 2)
        $errors[] = 'U heeft geen naam ingevuld.';

    // validation for email
    if(!strlen($email))
        $errors[] = 'U heeft geen email adres ingevuld.';
    else if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
        $errors[] = 'U heeft een ongeldig email adres ingevuld.';

    // return array with errors
    return $errors;
}

// initialization of variables with default values
$naam = '';
$email = '';
$errors = array();

// if the form has been submited
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    // overwrite the variables with the $_POST elements
    $naam = $_POST['naam'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    // validate the variables
    $errors = validate($naam, $email);

    // If there aren't any errors redirect to another page
    if(!count($errors))
    {
        // Here comes the place to send an email!!!

        header('Location: thankyou.html');
        exit;
    }
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>a titel</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="errors">
        <?php
            foreach($errors as $error)
            echo '<li>' . $error . '</li>';
        ?>
        </ul>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="naam" value="<?php echo $naam; ?>" />
            <input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" />
            <button type="submit">Verzenden</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this. I've got the email sending on submit but i'm not sure how to use the $name and $email in the syntax: I'm using 

 // overwrite the variables with the $_POST elements
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $recipient = 'chris@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Team Form';
    $mailheader = 'From: $email \r\n';
    $formcontent = '$name, $email';

and 

if(!count($errors)) 
  mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or  die("Error!");
        header('Location: contact.php');
        exit;
   }